# which variables should I be passing?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following view:

```
from models import Table
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext

def myget(request,
    template="project/p1.html",
    page_template="project/p2.html"):
    context = {
        'objects': Table.objects.all(),
        'page_template': page_template,
    }

    if request.is_ajax():
        template = page_template
    return render_to_response(template, context,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My urls file looks like:

```
url(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template': 'master.html'}), 
url(r'^p1', 'project.views.myget'),
```

I am including p1.html (which includes p2.html) in my master.html file as so:

```
{% include "project/p1.html" with objects=objects %}
```

I am including p2.html in my p1.html file as so:

```
{% include "project/p2.html" %}
```

I can see p1.html in my master.html file but not p2.html (when I load p1.html by itself, I can see p2.html). What am I missing? Do I need to load other variables besides "objects=objects"?

EDIT:
p1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/style/endless.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/style/endless_on_scroll.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>

{% include "project/p2.html" %}
</body>
</html>
```

p2.html:

```
{% load endless %}

<table>

{% paginate 100,100 objects %}
{% for object in objects %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ object.name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>


{% show_more %}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the p1.html template?

Comment: It's interesting to see p1.html and p2.html.

Comment: Yes please post complete contents of p1.html AND p2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass objects from your p1.html.

```
{% include "project/p2.html" with objects=objects %}
```

Plus there is something in your urls.py: you use direct_to_template instead of myget view which normally passes objects. 'direct_to_template' does not do that. So you should create a view that passes the objects instead of using 'direct_to_template'.

Comment: yeah, I tried that and that still doesn't work. When I do that, I can see p1.html, but not p2.html

Comment: @kristen What does it mean 'I can see'? What html you get from your browser when you can't see the correct output?

Comment: If I visit '127.0.0.1:8000 and look at the source code of the html, p1.html appears (ie I can see "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><script src="http:\/\/ajax.gooogleapis.com.......<body><\/body><\/html>"...which is clearly coming from p1.html). I cannot see the <table> .... </table> tags or the data generated from my model, which comes from p2.html.

Comment: @kristen Probably 'paginate' tag causes errors. Try to delete all the Django tags except {% for %}...{% endfor %}.

Comment: unfortunately, removing those tags don't help. I need to correct my previous comment. I can see the "<table></table>" tags coming from p2.html but no data (I don't see the <tr></tr> tags nor the data)

Comment: @kristen So, you have removed all the Django tags except {% for %}...{% endfor %}, you have added 'with objects=objects' to include of p2 in p1.html and there are no objects?

Comment: yes, correct. To clarify, loading p1.html in the browser shows everything correctly and as expected and the objects load fine. Loading master.html in the browser is when the objects from p2.html don't load.

Comment: @kristen Probably it's because of your urls.py. Please view my changed answer.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16017/discussion-between-sergzach-and-kristen)